# Do SWIG's array classes in carrays.i free C-allocated arrays that they wrap?

Tags: java, arrays, swig

If I have a SWIG-wrapped C function

`unsigned char* f()
{
  unsigned char* ptr;
  bar(ptr); //set ptr
  return ptr;
}`

and I use `array_class` or `array_functions` from SWIG's `carrays.i`, do their `delete` functions clean up the C-allocated memory?

That is, if I use `array_class` to define `%array_class(int, IntArray)`and do in Java

`IntArray ia = IntArray.frompointer(f());`

will the pointer returned by f() be freed when `ia` goes out of scope or, if using `array_functions`, when I explicitly invoke `delete()`?

The source code for `array_class` shows that the wrapped array class has a destructor:

`~NAME() {
  delete [] self;
}`

and `array_functions` has

`static void delete_##NAME(TYPE *ary) { %}
%{  delete [] ary; %}`

which leads me to believe it does, but the documentation doesn't say so and many examples I have seen use JNI code to create a copy of the array passed out by the C function, delete the original array, and return the copy back to Java. So I am unsure, with all the wrapping going on, what exactly these `delete` functions actually delete.

Comment: It does not free the data. It frees a copy constructed using the pointer, or it frees the data allocated when you create a new array with a fixed size. You can either create copies of the arrays created by C and delete the original array or pass on ownership to the target language. I believe there is an example of exactly this in 3.0 SWIG documentation for Java. What you can do is to wrap malloc and free to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the SWIG-generated array class's SwigOwn status that determines whether it owns the native memory is set to false. If you change this to true then doing myArray.delete() will indeed free the native memory it acquired by, for example,

```
 myArray ma = myArray.frompointer(new SWIGTYPE_p_char(function_that_returns_native_ptr))
```